# Resource for setting up Craft CMS Fields

Tags: fieldtypes, craft-features

It's a good 7 months after the last time this question was asked. I've been developing sites for a long time, expert with Wordpress, some Drupal, Joomla when forced. I can understand a good part of Craft but there really isn't the basic tutorial you'd generally see with other software that gives you an idea how to construct a site. The Happy Lager demo is more of a very quick showcase of how neat CraftCMS can be but it doesn't really go into just the very basics, like setting up fields properly.

I have seen the sparse resources. The paid video, which includes how to install the software, is not an option. Is there still nothing that does a reasonable job of just running through the process and approach to setting up a basic site using the system? In addition, are there any resource repositories, e.g. plugins, etc. so you don't need to reinvent everything? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a brain dump of learning resources I can think of.

- There's the [official documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/introduction).
- [Straight Up Craft](https://straightupcraft.com/) has some great learning articles and tutorials.
- They also happen to have the most [comprehensive list](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins) of Craft plugins until the official plugin store becomes a thing.
- The Craft site also has [help articles and tutorials](https://craftcms.com/support).
- The online [Craft demo site](https://demo.craftcms.com/) running Happy Lager.
- The [Happy Lager repo](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/HappyLager) if you'd prefer to setup locally.
- This Craft Stack Exchange site for Q&A.
- The [Craft Slack group](https://craftcms.com/community#slack) with people on from around the world practically 24x7.
- The [Craft feedback site](http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests) to see if a feature you'd like to ask for has already been asked.
- Sites like [Craft Cookbook](http://craftcookbook.net/) for help with Twig and templating recipes.
- Twig's [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html) for more Twig help.
- Mijingo has [many](https://mijingo.com/lessons/craft-2.5-quick-look/) [Craft-specific](https://mijingo.com/lessons/contact-form-in-craft-cms/) [video](https://mijingo.com/lessons/remote-asset-sources-in-craft/) [tutorials](https://mijingo.com/lessons/plugins-in-craft-3/) [both](https://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/craft-plugin-development/) [free](https://mijingo.com/products/bundles/craft-starter-pack/) [and](https://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/twig-templates-in-craft/) [commercial](https://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/craft-cms-tutorial/). Also, there are [articles and more](https://mijingo.com/craft).
- There are many user generated [Craft video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%22craft%20cms%22) up on YouTube.
- [craftlinklist.com](http://craftlinklist.com/) is a periodic newsletter where you can sign up for a curated list of Craft resources from around the web.

Comment: I love that the Mijingo point is actually eight separate links.

Comment: Mr. Irelan's got to be tickled pink over that one ;)

Comment: Also check out http://craftlinklist.com for a newsletter of the latest Craft links.

Comment: @JohnMorton Added to the answer!